# Numerical range of a symmetric positive matrix as an operator acting on Hilbert space

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $A$ be a $3\times 3$ real constant symmetric positive matrix, $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ a bounded Lipschitz domain and $(L^2(\Omega))^3$ the space of square integrable functions on $\Omega$.
I already know that the numerical range of $A$ is the interval $[\lambda_{min},\lambda_{max}]$ where $\lambda_{min}$ (resp. $\lambda_{max}$) is the smaller (resp. greatest) eigenvalue of $A$.  But, if we consider $A$ as an operator acting on the space $(L^2(\Omega))^3$, did then the numerical range still the same as above ?
For the definition of numerical range, one could consult for example  [math.wsu.edu/faculty/tsat/files/short.pdf](https://%20math.wsu.edu/faculty/tsat/files/short.pdf)

Comment: Your terminology of "numerical range" as the interval between smallest and largest eigenvalues is unfamiliar to me.  Can you cite a publication (author and title) where you saw it used this way?

Comment: @hardmath  for example : http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/tsat/files/short.pdf

Comment: Thanks, that's a good reference for the definition, worth editing into the body of your Question.   The problem posed is then whether the result for a $3\times 3$ matrix agrees with the wider application to $(L(\Omega))^3$.  I'll write something up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you consider $A$ as an operator, it is still a selfajoint operator with three-point spectrum. For any selfajoint operator, the numerical range is $[\lambda_\min,\lambda_\max]$.

Comment: Excuse me, I did not understand the following : "any selfadjoint operator", did you mean only the matrix operators like $A$ ? Or the all selfadjoint operator defined on a Hilbert space ?

Comment: "Any" is kind of the opposite of "only".  The property holds for any selfadjoint operator acting on any Hilbert space.

Comment: Excuse me, what did $\lambda_{min}$ and  $\lambda_{max}$ represent for a selfadjoint operator acting on a Hilbert space ?

Comment: The minimum and maximum elements of the spectrum.

Comment: Thank very much. Could you please give me a good reference about numerical range of selfadjoint operator on Hilbert space and its properties, in particular those you have mentioned in your answer ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know where this is treated with care. The fact that the numerical range is convex is the well-known Toeplitz-Hausdorff Theorem. Then you can use the Spectral Theorem to see that the numerical range is contained in the closed convex hull of the spectrum. Also with the Spectral Theorem, one shows that $\lambda_\min$ and $\lambda_\max$ are in the numerical range, which proves the equality.